# Find the maximum of every 60 elements in my data-MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a vector that contains a long list of data (time series). I would like to find the maximum of every 60 elements without going through manually C=[max(B(1:60)), etc... ] because it is a rather large data set. Is there a clean way of doing this? Thanks for any ideas! I appreciate it.

Comment: Reshape into a 60xN matrix, then apply max along each column.

Answer (score 2):

Oli's suggestion deserves to be made into a formal answer.  Try this:

```
C = max(reshape(B,60,[]));
```

Comment: What happens if the data isn't an exact multiple of 60 elements?

Comment: For the case when number of elements are not multiple of `60`, pad with minus infinites. Thus, if `B` is a column vector - `max(reshape(padarray(B,60-rem(numel(B),60),-Inf,'post'),60,[]))`. Leaving it to you to figure out for row vector case.

Comment: For max and min, I prefer to pad with NaN's instead. `max([1 nan])=1`, and `min([1 nan])=1`.

Comment: @SamRP To do the padding automatically, use `vec2mat(B,60,NaN).'` (or change `NaN` to whatever you want to pad with)

Answer (score 0):

As another option you can look at blkproc.

```
A= randn(600,1);
blkproc( A, [60,1], 'max');
```

blkproc is being phased out, so you will also have to look at blockproc.

Though, reshaping and taking the max will probably be more efficient as was mentioned in the comments.

```
max( reshape(A, [60, 10] ) )
```

[update]

As a note... don't use blkproc :-). Using a very large array (A), blkproc is 100x slower than the max,reshape.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'buffer' function.

```
A= randn(600,1);
max(buffer(A,60));
```

This solution works even when the length of the vector is not exact multiple of 60 and is faster in comparison to 'reshape' function.